# Want to translate an Image with 100% width and height on/off the screen with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, animation

So I have a full screen image, that on page load, is hidden. When the user clicks a link, the image appears by sliding from the bottom of the page. When the user then clicks the image, the image is wiped off the page using the opposite function.

Right now I'm using slideUp and slideDown. Unfortunately, this just wipes the image off the screen and does not translate it. I want the image to move off the page as if it were being translated down 2000 px or something.

I tried using animation like "bottom: +=2000" and stuff like that, but this produced the same "wiping" result.

Any idea how this could be done? Maybe it is impossible for an image with variable width / height?

Here is my basic code:

Html:

```
<div id="nav_link" class="nav_magazin">
    <p>Magazin</p>
</div>
<div id="magazin_overlay"><div id="mehr_overlay">mehr...</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#magazin_overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 50;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('images/block_cover.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.nav_magazin').click(function() {
    $('#magazin_overlay').slideDown('slow');
});

$('#magazin_overlay').click(function(){
    $('#mehr_overlay').hide();
    $(this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

issue because of, you are hiding the div

instead of this,

```
$('#magazin_overlay').click(function(){
    $('#mehr_overlay').hide();
    $(this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

try this,

```
$('#magazin_overlay').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp('slow');                  
});
```

Hope this help you..... 
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwzc9/153/)**

Comment: This unfortunately is not the issue. The "#mehr_overlay" is just the button it's not the 100% w/h image. As in, it's completely irrelevant to the animation going on. Sorry if that was confusing.